# Name conventions for Active Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, rails-activejob

I want to know if there are any naming conventions for Active Job classes. I saw different variants. For example, `verb + noun job` like `SendNotificationJob`, `SendNewUserInvitationJob` or `anything + noun` like `TweetNotifictorJob`, `GuestsCleanupJob`. What are your rules for a job naming?

Answer (score 5):

`verb + noun` is a reasonable template. If the particular actor is significant, then I like to use a convention like `verb + noun + actor`, such as `PublishArticleAsAuthorJob`, however that's only useful if the distinction of which actor is responsible for the job is significant. For example, I might expect that if there's also a `PublishArticleAsAdminJob` or might be in the future. Also I rename stuff a lot, so I'm most likely to just name it `PublishArticleJob` and then if I later make a `PublishArticleAsAdminJob` I'll rename the existing one to `PublishArticleAsAuthorJob`.

I also tend to order the words in terms of a hierarchy so it might be `resource + verb`. This is so when I'm scanning an alphabetical list of files/modules I can quickly see related items such as `ArticlePublishJob` and `ArticleCreateJob` next to each other in the list.

I like to keep my verbs to a finite set, for example `Build` (instantiate without persisting) `Create` (instantiate and persist), `Save` (save an instance that's been built elsewhere), `Find` (find in local db, filesystem, or data structure), `Fetch` (return if present, else generate or get, ensure immediately present for next time, and return).

A non-standard verb like `Publish` should correspond to a defined transition on the resource in question, so I would expect there to be a `publish!` method on the `Article` model. If the `Article` model does not know how to `publish` itself, and if for example publishing consists of creating a record in a list of published articles, then the job would be something like `CreatePublishingEntryJob` (`publishing_entries` is an awkward resource name that warrants more thought but it's beside the point here), which gets me back into standard verb territory.

I can't claim that my convention is "correct" here, but these details are intended to provide some ideas. The idea of a finite set of verbs came out of studying REST architecture, where instead of a PATCH to `/article/:id/publish`, I might do a POST to `/publish_article_jobs`, because the resource I'm actually acting on isn't Articles, it's Jobs.

Another example of making non-standard verbs into standard verbs would be to replace `tag an article` with `create a tagging` across the corresponding routes, controllers, jobs, etc.

Once again, just a set of ideas. Not claiming "rightness" status here.

My general rule of thumb for naming is this: If I can think of two or more possible names for a thing, I should keep thinking about that naming until there is only one possible name for it. This is great because later if I need a thing, and I use the same naming process to resolve down to one possible name, I can just type the resulting filename into my editor's file opener and voila, there's the file. Even if I wrote the code five years ago, I can think "I wonder if I have a ...`create_tagging_job.rb` and the presence of the file answers the question for me.

Comment: Love this! Especially the organizing by resource and limiting verb names